# Animate CAGradientLayer horizontally only

Tags: ios, objective-c, calayer, caanimation, cagradientlayer

I'm trying to animate a CAGradientLayer (the gradient, and the frame), and when I animate the frame down to 0, it shrinks up to the upper left corner of the view, and I want it to just animate out horizontally. Right now it's animating to 0 both horizontally and vertically.

Here's what the animation currently looks like:

[image: Animating CAGradientLayer]

What I want is for when it goes down to nothing, to just shrink horizontally ONLY, and remain the same height the entire time.

Here's the code I'm currently using:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
// Drawing code
if (!gradientLayer) {
    gradientLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    [gradientLayer setFrame:[self createRectForFrame:rect]];
    [gradientLayer setColors:@[(id)fromColor.CGColor, (id)toColor.CGColor]];
    [gradientLayer setStartPoint:CGPointMake(fillPct/100, 0.5)];
    [gradientLayer setEndPoint:CGPointMake(1.0, 0.5)];
    [self.layer addSublayer:gradientLayer];
}
else {
    [gradientLayer removeAllAnimations];

    [CATransaction begin];

    [CATransaction setAnimationDuration:ANIMATION_DURATION];
    CGRect newFrame = [self createRectForFrame:rect];
    CABasicAnimation *frameAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"frame"];
    [frameAnimation setDuration:ANIMATION_DURATION];
    [frameAnimation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
    [frameAnimation setFromValue:[NSValue valueWithCGRect:gradientLayer.bounds]];
    [frameAnimation setToValue:[NSValue valueWithCGRect:newFrame]];
    [frameAnimation setFillMode:kCAFillModeForwards];
    [frameAnimation setRemovedOnCompletion:NO];
    [gradientLayer setFrame:newFrame];
    [gradientLayer addAnimation:frameAnimation forKey:@"frame"];

    CGPoint startPoint = CGPointMake(MIN(fillPct/100, 0.99), 0.5);
    CABasicAnimation *startPointAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"startPoint"];
    [startPointAnimation setDuration:ANIMATION_DURATION];
    [startPointAnimation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
    [startPointAnimation setFromValue:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:gradientLayer.startPoint]];
    [startPointAnimation setToValue:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:startPoint]];
    [startPointAnimation setFillMode:kCAFillModeForwards];
    [startPointAnimation setRemovedOnCompletion:NO];
    [gradientLayer setStartPoint:startPoint];
    [gradientLayer addAnimation:startPointAnimation forKey:@"startPoint"];

    [CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{
        [self updateInnerLabelTextColor];
    }];

    [CATransaction commit];
}
[self bringInnerLabelToFront];
}

- (CGRect)createRectForFrame:(CGRect)frame {
if (fillPct == 0)
    return CGRectZero;
else if (fillPct >= 100)
    return frame;
else
    return CGRectMake(frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y, frame.size.width * (fillPct / 100), frame.size.height);
}
```

fillPct is the value the bar should be filled, between 0 and 100.

Comment: drawRect is not the right place for that code because it does not use Core Graphics, but Core Animation

Answer (score 2):

The problem is this line:

```
CGPoint startPoint = CGPointMake(MIN(fillPct/100, 0.99), 0.5);
```

If you change it to:

```
CGPoint startPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.5);
```

It would work as you want - without shrinking at the corner.

Or if you wish to keep your current code, change this value would work as well:

```
CGPoint startPoint = CGPointMake(MIN(fillPct/100, 0.0), 0.5);
```

Just tested it; it animates horizontally. Hope this helps.

***Update 1:***

I really did not experience the problem you mentioned in comment; but, I decided to look at it again. Since you did not provide any arbitrary value for the `rect` and the way you call this over and over, I came up with my own and tested it again.

I set up the `gradientLayer` with this value:

```
[gradientLayer setFrame:(CGRect){{150.0f, 240.0f}, 150.0f, 20.0f}];
```

In the first `CABasicAnimation`, for testing purpose, I changed this:

```
[frameAnimation setToValue:[NSValue valueWithCGRect:(CGRect){{150.0f, 240.0f}, 0.0f, 20.0f}]];
```

As you can see, it is exactly the same as the layer's rect, except that width, which is 0.0f. Imagine, that would cause the width to 0.

Does the above work? Yes.

Does the above work as the way you want? No.

The reason is that that would cause the frame to shrink uniformly - not what you want here.

So, add this when you are creating your `gradientLayer`:

```
gradientLayer.anchorPoint = (CGPoint){0.0f, 0.5f};
```

Again, I tested it and it's running before me at this moment of writing. It's fun to look at by the way.

Hope this, again, helps.

Comment: I tried changing that line, but when the fillPct value = 0, which returns CGRectZero from the createRectForFrame function, it still shrinks into the corner instead of just shrinking horizontally.